# Como convertir a fechahora en SQL 2022-03-04T14:09:18.7262683-06:00

Tags: sql-server

Alguien me podría ayudar a saber como convierto este formato "2022-03-04T14:09:18.7262683-06:00"  a un datetime en SQL o a saber que formato es para investigar más.

Muchas gracias

Comment: va a depender de si quieres la hora local o no. El `-06:00` es un offset, por lo que el tipo de dato a usar es realmente `DATETIMEOFFSET`

Answer (score 0):

Creo que a datetime directo no se podria, mas que nada porque contiene muchos milisegundos etc, pero a datetime2 o datetimeoffset podria ser

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2,'2022-03-04T14:09:18.7262683-06:00')
//Salida 2022-03-04 14:09:18.7262683
SELECT CONVERT(datetimeoffset,'2022-03-04T14:09:18.7262683-06:00')
//Salida 2022-03-04 14:09:18.7262683+65530
```

para solo datetime deverias de recortar parte de la informacion podrias usar un string_split, solo por dar un ejemplo, pero perderias parte de la informacion

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, (SELECT TOP 1 Value FROM STRING_SPLIT('2022-03-04T14:09:18.7262683-06:00','.')))
//Salida 2022-03-04 14:09:18.000
```